# Calculating geometry for a clipped layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, calculate-geometry

Working with ArcGIS Pro. I'm trying to calculate stream length for areas outside of state land. I've tried this two separate ways and was successful in getting the layer that I'm looking for, but for some reason, I go to calculate geometry and it spits out the length for the full stream not the modified/short stream (I know this since I can compare IDs and their respective lengths). This seems like it should be simple... Am I missing something? How do I calculate the new stream length?

Here are the two ways that I have created my working layers:

1. I pulled in my stream layer and used the Erase tool to remove the streams that overlapped the state land layer.
2. I used the Clip tool with the stream layer to the state land layer. I figured if I could calculate the stream length from the streams within the state land, then I could substract that from the total stream length and get stream length outside of the state land.

Comment: I also think both should work. How are you calculating length?

Comment: I open the attribute table, right click on the length column and say calculate geometry. Opens a popup that allows me to choose how I want to calculate which attribute. I choose the length column, that I want to calculate length, by metric, and say OK. The length column is from the original layer...I'll try creating a new column/field specifically in this layer and see if that could be the issue?

Comment: It would worth a try, but creating a new field didn't work. There's got to be something I'm missing...something that pulls the old data over.

Comment: I'm in Pro...so there isn't an edit mode to turn on? I'm the only user and I created the stream network file that I'm creating these other layers from.

Comment: But what is the data source format? Shapefile, geodatabase, some server based dataset, do you have it in onedrive/dropbox that could be file locking it?